# Coffeescript & rightjs, Div Click

Tags: coffeescript, sinatra, rightjs

I am working in sinatra, with Coffeescript and rightjs.

in the body of the html I have a div

```
<div id="loginimage">
<img src="/images/login.png">
</div>
```

and a footer element

```
<footer>
<div id="footer">
<form action="/login" class="login" method="post">
</form>
</div>
</footer>
```

and finally my coffee script looks like:

```
$(document).onReady ->
  "#loginimage".onClick ->
    "#footer".toggle "fade"
```

I want to be able to click on the div with id loginimage and toggle the footer element, right now I have it toggling the div with id footer, how can I select html5 elements like footer? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not that familiar with RightJS but I suspect that you'd just use a normal `<footer>` selector in the string:

```
$(document).onReady ->
  "#loginimage".onClick ->
    "footer".toggle "fade"
```

No hash (`id` selector), no dot (class selector), just the element name. The [String documentation](http://rightjs.org/docs/string) for RightJS even includes things like this:

```
"div.something".addClass('marked');
"div#something".highlight();
```

so presumably the string that you're calling RightJS methods on is just any old selector.

Comment: Yeah, I was about to post http://rightjs.org/tutorials/what-new-in-rjs2#events-delegation. The String class now has all the same API for events handling as the Element unit.